# Always block - Do RHS signals in an assignment ,inside always block will be added to senstivity list?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Do RHS  signals in an assignment ,inside always block will be added to senstivity list ? if that is true, may i know, why the following code is not working ?

```
 `timescale 1ns/1ps

  module tb();

    reg clk=0;

    initial begin
      #10 clk = 1;
      #1000;
      $finish();
  end

  always@(*)begin
    #10 clk=!clk;
  end

  initial begin
    $recordfile("wave.trn");
    $recordvars();
  end

 endmodule
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a useful answer if you follow the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, what is happening, what were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not working for a different reason:
An always block is not sensitive to signal changes until all actions have finished.

Thus **after** your clock has toggled, the always block waits for a new clock event, which is not forthcoming.

To generate a clock you should use something like:

```
initial
begin
   clk = 1'b0;
   forever
      #(CLK_PERIOD/2) clk = ~clk;
end
```

Comment: Hi,  I am trying understand the always@(*) means. My understanding is all rhs signals will be added to sensitivity list. here clk will be added to sensitivity list and clk will be generated

Comment: The clock is in the sensitivity list thus the always will be triggered with `#10 clk = 1;` Then it will ignore all inputs until it is finished. It is finished **after** #10 clk=!clk; has been executed. Thus that change itself is not seen as it has already happened.

Comment: always@(*)begin
    #10 clk=!clk;
  endalways@(*)begin
    #10 clk=!clk;
  end